# Can't open application from link on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am trying to open my app from a link, this is how I set it up on the Android Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".EmailVerificationActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="emailverification.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This works great on pre-lollipop, but it just doesn't work on Android 5. Anyone has any idea why?

I already tried setting `pathPrefix` and `path` and it didn't work either.

Comment: I am stuck on the same issue :( please let me know if you get around it